# Can i use aws cloudwatch log on multiple instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I have multiple instances.
So i want to monitor server and application log for each instances on cloudwatch.

Can i use aws cloudwatch log on multiple instances?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to? The service would be useless if you could only pick one EC2 server to use it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but beware that if you pick the same log group / log stream for every instance you'll get comingled messages (which are painful to debug).

It's easy to change the configuration (I recommend using log streams named after the instance ID), but you have to do this when you provision the instance (which means that you actually need a provisioning step, rather than just spinning up an AMI).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.

Simply install the Cloudwatch log agent on each of the instance that you have and you are good to go

For instructions about installing and configuring Cloudwatch log agent [click here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/EC2NewInstanceCWL.html)

Comment: Does this mean that cloudwatch takes care of synchronization of the log streams from multiple instances in auto scaling groups and so on?

Comment: Yes it does. For more details check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-monitoring.html